# How to Invoke a WF3.5 WorkFlow from a WF4 Workflow

Tags: workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

anyone kwnos how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no out of the box way of doing this. Basically you have two options:

1. Use WCF to communicate between the 2 workflows. The WF3 workflow would be started by using a Send activity in WF4 sending a message to a WF3 ReceiveActivity. In that case neither has to know about how the other is implemented.
2. Create a custom activity and use that to communicate with the WF3 runtime and start the WF3 workflow.

The Interop activity that ships with WF4 doesn't support the WF3 InvokeWorkflowActivity so that is a no go.